# Project after Mavenizing 

Tags: maven, project

Today is the day i (with little hesitation) mavenized my project. All is well, things compile, but OMG .. what happened to my project layout?

"src" is repeated twice, one is a source folder the other one is not. I seem to be missing sub-folders under src down below ... it's a mess.

Could someone please let me know where it all went wrong?

[image]

Comment: What did you use to get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Maven standards,
all your Java source should go in: `src/main/java`
Similarly, all the test code should go in: `src/main/test`

and, finally, resources: `src\main\resources`

What **Eclipse** has done is that, these locations are segregated. Don't see those as different `src` folders... rather look at the full path.

Also, I don't believe that any content should be missing from this. Why don't you try `Ctrl+shift+R` to open the file explorer and try searching the file there.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong as you may see that the first "src" node is for java classes, the second "src" node is for other than java classes such as resources. they are separated for the different purposes.

Regards,

Charlee Ch.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Charlee that there seems nothing wrong at first glance. But please clarify: What source folders are you missing?
And remember: At least in "java-mode" Eclipse sometimes hides certain foldes f.e. build targets and "duplicates" others in the view for convenience, here the different java-src folders.